# How to use an object method as a callback function

Tags: php

I have the below method in a singleton class

```
private function encode($inp)
{
    if (is_array($inp) {
        return array_map('$this->encode', $inp);
    } else if is_scalar($inp) {
        return str_replace('%7E', rawurlencode($inp));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

this works fine as an ordinary function

```
function encode($inp)
{
    if (is_array($inp) {
        return array_map('encode', $inp);
    } else if is_scalar($inp) {
        return str_replace('%7E', rawurlencode($inp));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

when using inside a class i'm getting the below error:

> PHP Warning:  array_map(): The first
>   argument, '$this->rfc_encode', should
>   be either NULL or a valid callback

Please could anybody help me to fix this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [PHP Manual on Callbacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback):

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

So try

```
return array_map(array($this, 'encode'), $inp);
```

Comment: Also, method `encode` must be [public](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: @Dejv Actually, I've tested it with a **private class method** and it works either. I'm using PHP 7.0.13.

Comment: what if the custom function requires 2 params

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam in case of array_map, the argument list is variadic

Answer (score -3):

Release the single code from **$this->encode**.

```
> private function encode($inp) {
>     if (is_array($inp) {
>         return array_map($this->encode, $inp);
>     } else if is_scalar($inp) {
>         return str_replace('%7E', rawurlencode($inp));
>     } else {
>         return '';
>     } }
```

Hope that clears the issue.

Comment: `$this->encode` has no value.  There are no real function pointers in PHP, so this is not valid PHP for a callback.  It'd only work if you had something like `$this->encode = array(&$this, 'encode');`, which is just a hack to make this specific code work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Chao and Fero.