# PHP FILTER_CALLBACK in OOP Class

Tags: php, filter

Hi I've been playing around with phps filter class getting and have come across a snag with the filter_callback filter.

the following rough bit of code works but shows an error every time

> Warning: filter_var() [function.filter-var]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback in /Users/Rob/sites/test_val.php on line 12

```
class test

{

public function callback($string)
{

$var = filter_var($string, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => $this->foo($string)));

} 

public function foo($string){

echo $string;


}

}


$test = new test();

$string = 'test';

$tested = $test->callback($string);
```

am i calling the function correctly or is there a different way?

Comment: *(reference)* [Callback pseudotype](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use an object method as a callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350762/how-to-use-an-object-method-as-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 9):

```
$this->foo($string)
```

...should be...

```
array($this, 'foo')
```

When using a method as a callback, you need to provide the reference in this manner.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: thanks for your help, is their a way to pass multiple variables to the function callback?

Comment: @Robert The function uses the callback, not you, so you can't pass additional arguments.

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me :)

```
 <?php
    class myClass {
     public function myFunc($var){
       return filter_var($var, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options'=> 'self::myCallback'));
     }
     public function myCallback(){
      return true;
     }
    }
$obj = new myClass();

var_dump($obj->myFunc("myname@gmail.com"));
//output:- bool(true)

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo filter_var('wo9w9w9', FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => array(new MyFilter(), 'filter1'))) . PHP_EOL;
```

options You can directly transfer object instance, like **$this** or new self ,