# array_map in php with callback OOP

Tags: php, oop, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use an object method as a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350762/how-to-use-an-object-method-as-a-callback-function)

Usually I used array_map with procedural code, but in this case I'm working in OOP and the callback should be "this->id2areas", but It's not working. Is there anyway of put this callback with OOP?

```
ERROR MESSAGE: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'this->id2area' not found or invalid function name
```

MY CODE
 =================================================================================

```
$this->context->assign('user_areas', implode(', ', array_map('id2area',   explode(',', $this->user['areas']))));     
explode(',', $this->user['areas']))));



function id2area($id) {//callback
    if ($id == 0) {
        return 'National';
    }
    $query = "SELECT area FROM area WHERE id = $id";
    return DB::fetch_instance()->slave->fetchColumn($query);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In PHP, you can use an array to associate an object and a method call as a callable

```
array_map(array($this, 'id2area'), $array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: And, since `id2area()` doesn't actually use the `$this` instance context, I would recommend making it a `static function`.  Then referenced as `array_map(array('className','id2area'), $array)`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Or in most cases, `array(__CLASS__, 'id2area')` :)

Answer (score 8):

PHP callbacks for objects is a bit different then global functions.

```
//Global function callback
array_map('id2area', $data);

// Object function
array_map(array($object, 'id2area'), $data)
// - or -
array_map(array($this, 'id2area'), $data)

// Static class function
array_map(array('Class_Name', 'id2area'), $data)
// - or -
array_map('Class_Name::id2area', $data)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this as an anonymous function like:

```
array_map(
    function($arg) {
        return $this->id2area($arg);
    },
    explode(',', $this->user['areas'])
);
```