# Call static function with parameter as a callback

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass static function as a callback with parameter, as I'm using old version of PHP, I can't use anonymous function, as it's done in original code https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki , in section "Using all these options".

```
class SampleClass {

    function __construct( ) {

    }

    static function generateHTML($markup, $data) {
        require_once( 'lib/Mustache/Autoloader.php' );

        Mustache_Autoloader::register();

        $mengine = new Mustache_Engine(array(
            'escape' => /* Here I need to pass escapeMustache function */
        ));

        $renderer = new TempRenderer($data, false);
        echo $mengine->render($markup, $renderer);
    }
    static function escapeMustache($value) {
        return $value;
    }

}
```

What's the best way to pass custom escape function?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming the callback is expected to have one parameter as you have defined it, pass the object context and function nam as an array:  `Mustache_Engine(array('escape' => array('SampleClass','escapeMustache'))`

Comment: Can you use a [variable function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank you very much, it worked. I feel now so dumb as I tried this method at first time, but made small syntax mistake in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use an object method as a callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350762/how-to-use-an-object-method-as-a-callback-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelBerkowski

```
Mustache_Engine(array('escape' => array('SampleClass','escapeMustache'))
```