# PHP OOP select method from another class with a PSR4 Autoloader

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I am trying to select a method called fallback inside the walker class of bootstrap.
The class name is called WPNavwalker.

I have tried a lot of thing but it didn't work.
like \Namespace\classes\Classname::fallback, Namespace\classes\Classname::fallback

See my code:

```
use Namespace\classes\WPNavwalker;
public static function show_menu() 
{
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'primary',
        'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
        'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
        'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
        'fallback_cb'     => 'Classname::fallback',
        'walker'          => new \Namespace\classes\WPNavwalker()   
    ));
}
```

I just need to know how i can select that method

this is the error : Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'fallback'.

```
public static function fallback( $args ) {
            if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {

                /* Get Arguments. */
                $container       = $args['container'];
                $container_id    = $args['container_id'];
                $container_class = $args['container_class'];
                $menu_class      = $args['menu_class'];
                $menu_id         = $args['menu_id'];

                // initialize var to store fallback html.
                $fallback_output = '';

                if ( $container ) {
                    $fallback_output .= '<' . esc_attr( $container );
                    if ( $container_id ) {
                        $fallback_output .= ' id="' . esc_attr( $container_id ) . '"';
                    }
                    if ( $container_class ) {
                        $fallback_output .= ' class="' . esc_attr( $container_class ) . '"';
                    }
                    $fallback_output .= '>';
                }
                $fallback_output .= '<ul';
                if ( $menu_id ) {
                    $fallback_output .= ' id="' . esc_attr( $menu_id ) . '"'; }
                if ( $menu_class ) {
                    $fallback_output .= ' class="' . esc_attr( $menu_class ) . '"'; }
                $fallback_output .= '>';
                $fallback_output .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr__( 'Add a menu', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Add a menu', 'wp-bootstrap-navwalker' ) . '</a></li>';
                $fallback_output .= '</ul>';
                if ( $container ) {
                    $fallback_output .= '</' . esc_attr( $container ) . '>';
                }

                // if $args has 'echo' key and it's true echo, otherwise return.
                if ( array_key_exists( 'echo', $args ) && $args['echo'] ) {
                    echo $fallback_output; // WPCS: XSS OK.
                } else {
                    return $fallback_output;
                }
            }
        }
```

link to documentation: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use an object method as a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350762/how-to-use-an-object-method-as-a-callback-function)

Comment: I don't think so if it was a duplicate the menu was not showing up

Comment: Where do you define your Classname::fallback? how exactly the function looks?

Comment: It's in another file in another class but in the same folder..

Comment: See the example above and gonna post the documentation as well from github

Comment: So you call the method with [NameOfYourClass, NameOfYourMethod]  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954168/php-how-to-use-a-class-function-as-a-callback

Comment: Getting stuck nothing is working it can't be so hard

Answer (score -1):

This works and mimics your code:

```
<?php
// this is the class defining a callback
class MyClass
{
    public static function ThisIsCallback($args)
    {
        var_dump([
            'I am your callback',
            $args
        ]);
    }
}

// this is a class /w method calling the callback
class AnotherClass
{
    public function whatever($params, $callback)
    {
        var_dump([
            'I am whatever'
        ]);
        $callback($params);
    }
}

// this is the actual call
(new AnotherClass)->whatever([1,2,'I am your param'],[MyClass, ThisIsCallback]);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "I am whatever"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "I am your callback"
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
    [2]=>
    string(15) "I am your param"
  }
}
```

Comment: But in the documentation he doesn't pass any arguments? How would the actual call than be? And i am developing my first theme, so i am starter at coding and in the structure of wordpress oop we are selecting methods inside classes like this: array(new self, 'function name'); 'I am calling a static function here inside a class'

Comment: Hopefully you can help me out with it, working already for a few hours on it haha

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the simplest example demonstrating the problem? This has nothing to do with WP, rather how you pass a static method as an argument to a function.