# Argument 1 passed to League\Csv\Statement::where() must be callable, string given with where statement in csv league

Tags: csv, cakephp-4.x

I'm working on a CakePHP 4 project, using CSV League to read csv file.
My file's contents:

```
EMAIL
correctmail@gmail.com
nokmail@gmail.com
...
```

I follow [this](https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/reader/statement/#filtering-constraint) example:
In my controller class, I define function filterByEmail:

```
function filterByEmail(array $record): bool
{
    return (bool) filter_var($record[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Inside the private function readFileImport($filename):

```
$reader = Reader::createFromPath('path_to_my_csv_file', 'r');
$stmt = (new Statement())
    ->offset(1)
    ->limit(10)
    ->where('filterByEmail');

$records = $stmt->process($reader);
```

I receive the error "Argument 1 passed to League\Csv\Statement::where() must be callable, string given."
What's wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is that code located? is it in a file that has a namespace?

Comment: @ndm I edited the post in reply to your question

Comment: When you say "_in my controller class_", do you mean that you define the `filterByEmail` function as a method of the controller class, just like `readFileImport`?

Comment: @ndm Yes, exactly!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350762/how-to-use-an-object-method-as-a-callback-function